# Jest + mockImplementation + Number of calls: 0

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I am using `Jest` as testing module. Jest spy function is not called, it says `Number of calls: 0`.

**a.test.js**

```
 const request = require('request-promise');
    const moduleA = require('./a');
    test('Update function', async () => {
    const postSpy = jest.spyOn(request, 'post').mockImplementation((input) => input);
    await moduleA();
    expect(postSpy).toBeCalledWith({
    method: 'POST',
    uri:"fsdsfd",
    headers: {
     'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: {
      A:A,
      B:B      
    },
    json: true 
});
    });
```

**a.js**

```js
const request = require('request-promise');

module.exports = async () => {
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'fsdsfd',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: {
      A: A,
      B: B,
    },
    json: true,
  };

  try {
    const selectResult = await request(options);
    return selectResult;
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
};
```

It throws error as `expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(...expected)` and `Number of calls: 0`. I think the mocked function is not called. I searched a lot regarding this but no hope. Any ideas??

**EDIT**

My Guess is that there is no method `post` in `request-promise`.

**EDIT FOR REQUEST>POST()**

```
    request.post({
      uri: 'fsdsfd',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: {
      A: A,
     B: B,
    },
    json: true,
    }, function(err, resp){
      if(err){
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        console.log(resp);
        return(resp)--------------->
      }
    });
```

**ASYNC AWAIT EDIT**

```
const ss = await request.post({
          uri: 'fsdsfd',
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: {
          A: A,
         B: B,
        },
        json: true,
        });
return ss;
```

Here if you use this the arrow (-->) is not getting called so its not assign in test file so I can't check for result values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<del>You use `request(...)` instead of using `request.post(...)`, so you need mock `request` function not `request.post` method.</del>

E.g.
`a.js`:

```js
const request = require('request-promise');

module.exports = async () => {
  var options = {
    uri: 'fsdsfd',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: {
      A: 'A',
      B: 'B',
    },
    json: true,
  };

  try {
    const selectResult = await request.post(options);
    return selectResult;
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
};
```

`a.test.js`:

```js
const request = require('request-promise');
const moduleA = require('./a');

jest.mock('request-promise', () => {
  return {
    post: jest.fn(),
  };
});

describe('59261385', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  test('Update function', async () => {
    request.post.mockResolvedValueOnce({ result: [] });
    const actual = await moduleA();
    expect(actual).toEqual({ result: [] });
    expect(request.post).toBeCalledWith({
      uri: 'fsdsfd',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: {
        A: 'A',
        B: 'B',
      },
      json: true,
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59261385/a.test.js (11.669s)
  59261385
    ✓ Update function (33ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |     87.5 |      100 |      100 |    83.33 |                   |
 a.js     |     87.5 |      100 |      100 |    83.33 |                20 |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.599s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59261385

Update:

You can use `jest.spyOn` too.

`a.test.js`:

```js
const request = require('request-promise');
const moduleA = require('../a');

describe('59261385', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  test('Update function', async () => {
    const postSpy = jest.spyOn(request, 'post').mockResolvedValueOnce({ result: [] });
    const actual = await moduleA();
    expect(actual).toEqual({ result: [] });
    expect(postSpy).toBeCalledWith({
      uri: 'fsdsfd',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: {
        A: 'A',
        B: 'B'
      },
      json: true
    });
  });
});
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jestjs-jgye4

Comment: Thanks for your time. Also I tried to use `request.post` but in that case the result is not get assigned

Comment: @Subburaj Your edited code is wrong. 1. `try/catch` statement will not catch the exception from an asynchronous operation. You need to use `async/await`. 2. You return the `resp` from the callback function, the `resp` will not return to the caller, because its context is the callback function. I can't help until you make your code correctly

Comment: Any ideas?? Any mistake I did in above code?? Im literally new to `Jest` and `testing`

Comment: THanks. Still 1 more clarifications im using `jest.spyOn()` whether its not possible to accomplish with that? Please see my question it has that `spyOn`. Also `mockImplementation()`

Comment: @Subburaj Yes. You can use both `jest.mock` and `jest.spyOn`, please check the update part

Comment: im getting error as below  `expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected
    + Received

    - Object { result: [] }
    + Promise {} `